# Are maintenance manual airframe lifetime limitations binding?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-maintenance

An IA told me that component lifetime limitations, even when published in the `Airworthiness Limitations` section of the service manual, are not binding. They can be maintained *on condition*, completely superseding the published instructions.

In a related vein, I found the following section in an airframe manual:

> Extension of airframe life exceeding 5,000h can be done for individual aircraft only after a comprehensive airframe inspection carried out by the manufacturer according to an approved program.

Under what conditions does *on condition* apply to published airframe lifetime limitations as well?

Does it matter if the manufacturer is still in business?

Answer (score 1):

If the manufacturer is not in business you will have to talk to the local FSDO to find out if there is a way to comply with the airframe inspection. Your IA ***may*** be correct from a FAR point of view (and that is debatable), but an insurance company will likely deny any claims for any incidents or accidents if you did not comply with the manufacturer's maintenance and inspection instructions, and a court would likely side with them, leaving you holding the bag for any damages or liability.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful to know. Do you have links to flesh out why the IA's opinion may be debatable, as well as why the insurance and court will likely deny any claims? That's a very powerful assertion, and while it has the ring of truth to it it would be nice to see that backed up by case law and/or opposing legal interpretations.

Comment: In a battle between an IA and a FSDO, the FSDO almost always wins. Ask the IA if he/she will put his/her opinion in writing and defend it against the FSDO saying otherwise. That will be your sign. As to what happens with your insurance claim, call any aviation insurance broker and ask. If I were you, I would find out who owns the type certificate for the aircraft and go to them. Links are helpful but common sense more so. Completely abandoned type certificates are few and far between. Which aircraft is your question about?